Solution of $3^{b+1} = 2^{n+2} - 5$ and $3^{b+1} = 2^{n+2} + 1$ in natural numbers
In an attempt to solve a rather interesting task, I encountered a problem. I need to solve the following exponential equations in natural numbers: $3^{b+1} = 2^{n+2} - 5$ and $3^{b+1} = 2^{n+2} + 1$. I was able to find a couple of solutions for this equation, and tried to limit the number of solutions by multiplicities of 81 and 64, but this did not give results. Can you please help me solve them?

For the second we can use the proven Catalan conjecture (although there is surely a simpler solution , but I am notoriously bad to find such proofs) , for the first Pillai's conjecture predicts only a finite many solutions (again there is surely an easier method to prove that there is  only one solution).

I assume $b=0$ is ruled out , otherwise we would also have $3^1=2^3-5$

By a theorem of Bennett (2003) the equation $|2^x-3^y|=z$ has at most one solution unless $z\in{1,5,7,13,23}$. For these particular values $z\in{1,5}$ there are precisely $3$ solutions. For $z\in{7,13,23}$ there are precisely $2$ solutions. See here: https://oeis.org/A219551

@Servaes Great result , I wonder whether there is an easy way to decide for huge $n$ whether there is one solution or none.

By a theorem of Bennett (2003) the equation $|2^x-3^y|=z$ has at most one solution unless $z\in\{1,5,7,13,23\}$. For these particular values $z\in\{1,5\}$ there are precisely $3$ solutions. For $z\in\{7,13,23\}$ there are precisely $2$ solutions. See here: https://oeis.org/A219551
For $z=1$ and $z=5$ the solutions are
$$|2^1-3^1|=1,\qquad|2^2-3^1|=1,\qquad|2^3-3^2|=1,$$
$$|2^3-3^1|=5,\qquad|2^2-3^2|=5,\qquad|2^5-3^3|=5,$$
from which you can pick the solutions to your equations.
